# How do I inject dependencies into AngularJS controller tests without using Jasmine-specific inject()

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to wrap my brain around dependency injection in AngularJS. Let's say this is my very exciting application code:

```js
function PrideRockCtrl($scope, King) {
  $scope.king = King;
}
  
angular.module('Characters', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('King', function() {
    return "Mufasa";
  });
```

I want to test `PrideRockCtrl`. If I follow examples in the documentation and in the tutorial, I could use the `module('Characters')` to configure the injector and use `inject()` to get some dependencies. i.e.:

```js
describe('Pride Rock', function() {
  beforeEach(module('Characters'));
  it('should be ruled by Simba', inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var ctrl = $controller(PrideRockCtrl, {$scope: scope});
    expect(scope.king).toEqual("Mufasa");
  }));
});
```

This works fine, but this isn't a cross-test-framework solution. The `module()` and `inject()` test helpers are only compatible with Jasmine.

#### What's the best way to manually accomplish the same dependency injection without using `module()` or `inject()`?

I came up with this:

```js
describe('Pride Rock', function() {
  it('should be ruled by Mufasa', function() {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['Characters']);
    var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
    var scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
    var king = $injector.get('King');
    var ctrl = $controller(PrideRockCtrl, {$scope: scope, King: king});
    expect(scope.king).toEqual("Mufasa");
  });
});
```

This seems very verbose. Is there a better way?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnlindquist/d63Y3/

Answer (score 4):

The simplest possible version, without using modules would look like this:

```js
describe('Pride Rock', function() {

    it('should be ruled by Simba', inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        var scope = $rootScope.$new();
        var ctrl = $controller(PrideRockCtrl, {
            $scope: scope,
            King:"Mufasa"
        });
        expect(scope.king).toEqual("Mufasa");
    }));
});
```

In fact you were pretty close with your attempts, the only thing missing was a local dependency in a controller (`King:"Mufasa"`).

In the tests like those, where we do focus on a one, selected class only it is not necessary to use the $injector, as we can manually mock / stub our dependencies. At the end of the day $injector is just giving instances of objects so we can create those our self as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution that does not use [inject()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.inject) or [module()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.module). Those are only supported for Jasmine and I'm looking for a cross-test-framework solution.

Also, I don't want to manually mock out the King service. I want to use the actual one.

Answer (score 4):

Angular controllers are just JS functions.  If you don't want anything injected, just call them.

```
describe('king should be set', function() {
  var scope = {};
  var lion = "Simba";
  PrideController(scope, lion);
  expect(scope.king).toEqual(lion)
});
```